# Why does my square drawing function in python not shift down a row?

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

```
from graphics import *

def patch2():
    win = GraphWin("pattern", 100,100)
    TLX = 0
    TLY = 0
    BRX = 20
    BRY = 20
    for i in range(5):
        for i in range(5):
            r = Rectangle(Point(TLX,TLY), Point(BRX,BRY))
            r.draw(win)
            BRX += 20
            TLX += 20
            print(BRY)
        BRY = BRY + 20
        TLY = TLY + 20

patch2()
```

the purpose of the code is to draw 25 boxes (5x5).
The second for loop works, and draws 5 boxes across the top row of the graphics window, but it doesn't do the other 4 rows. TL AND BR stand for top left and bottom right (x and y coordinates)

Comment: Shouldn't you reset `BRX` to 20 and `TLX` to 0 after `BRY = BRY + 20` and `TLY = TLY + 20`?

Comment: Also, you use the same variable name `i` for the two loops. One should be changed e.g. to `j`.

Comment: @JohanC, since `i` isn't used by the code inside the loops, it's perfectly fine using the same variable name (or `_`) for both loops.  Look into how `for ... in range(...)` works for insight as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding `TLX = 0` after the inner `for` loop fixes the drawing but also resetting `BRX = 20` fixes the code.  We can simplify things a bit by tossing the `BR*` variables:

```
from graphics import *

def patch2():
    tl_x, tl_y = 0, 0

    for _ in range(5):
        for _ in range(5):
            r = Rectangle(Point(tl_x, tl_y), Point(tl_x + 20, tl_y + 20))
            r.draw(win)
            tl_x += 20

        tl_x = 0
        tl_y += 20

win = GraphWin("pattern", 100, 100)

patch2()
```

Or, we can make use of the `Point` classes inherited methods and make the design more point-oriented:

```
from graphics import *

def patch2():
    top_left = Point(0, 0)
    bottom_right = Point(20, 20)

    for _ in range(5):
        for _ in range(5):
            r = Rectangle(top_left, bottom_right)
            r.draw(win)
            top_left.move(20, 0)
            bottom_right.move(20, 0)

        top_left.move(-100, 20)
        bottom_right.move(-100, 20)

win = GraphWin("pattern", 100, 100)

patch2()
```